# Jersey Test @Autowired field in tested class is null

Tags: java, spring, junit, jersey, jersey-client

I have a little problem. I think this is typical question. However, I can't find good example. My application is using Jersey. And I want to test controller by client as test. Controller has private field - StudentService. When I debug test I see, that field is null. This leads to error. And I need to inject this field. I tried this:
My Controller

```
@Path("/student")
@Component
public class StudentResourse {
    @Autowired
    private StrudentService service; // this field Spring does not set

    @Path("/getStudent/{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Student getStudent(@PathParam("id") long id) {
         return service.get(id);
    }  
}
```

My JUnit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:config.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners({ DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
public class StudentResourseTest extends JerseyTest {
private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.example.servlet";
private static final String FILE_DATASET = "/data.xml";
@Autowired
private StudentService service; // this field is setted by Spring, but I do not need this field for test

public StudentResourseTest() {
    super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder(PACKAGE_NAME).build());
}

@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
    return new HTTPContainerFactory();
}

@Override
protected AppDescriptor configure() {
    return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("restful.server.resource")
            .contextParam("contextConfigLocation",
                    "classpath:/config.xml").contextPath("/")
            .servletClass(SpringServlet.class)
            .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
            .requestListenerClass(RequestContextListener.class).build();
}

@Test
@DatabaseSetup(FILE_DATASET)
public void test() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ClientResponse response = resource().path("student").path("getStudent")
                .path("100500").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
        Student student = (Student) response.getEntity(Student.class);
}  }
```

I guees, that problem is in test class. Because, when I run my application not in test, I can directly request students and everything working fine. But when I test classes, internal field of Controller does not setted. How to fix this bug? Thanks for your answers.

This is in my config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
<bean id="StudentResourse" class="com.example.servlet.StudentResourse">
    <property name="service" ref="studentService" />
</bean>
<bean id="service" class="com.example.service.StudentServiceImpl" />
```

Comment: Does your `config.xml` scan and generate the `StudentResourse` bean? Please show us.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I posted this just now

Comment: Are we talking about `StudentController` or `StudentResourse` here?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, sorry, I renamed some my classes to not to show some confidential information

Comment: First, if you have `@Autowired`, you don't need `<property>` for that field.

Comment: Second, your class is already annotated with `@Component`. Adding a `<bean>` declaration will add a second bean of that type in your context. Remove one or the other.

Comment: It did not help. studentService still null

Answer (score 1):

One issue may be that you're trying to configure your test application in constructor and in `configure()` method. Use one or another but not both because in this case your `configure()` method is not invoked and hence you may not be using `SpringServlet` and everything that is defined in this method.

Comment: I remove costructor from test class. But this did not help. Also, I removed excess declaration in config.xml. But this did not help too.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://github.com/jiunjiunma/spring-jersey-test and http://geek.riffpie.com/unit-testing-restful-jersey-services-glued-together-with-spring/

Idea is to get a hold of the application context inside jersey by using ApplicationContextAware interface. There after we can grab the exact bean already created by spring, in your case, `StudentService`. Below example shows a mocked version of the dependency, `SampleService`, used to test the resource layer apis.

Resource class delegating the processing to a service layer

```
@Component
@Path("/sample")
public class SampleResource {

    @Autowired
    private SampleService sampleService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path ("/{id}")
    public Sample getSample(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Sample sample = sampleService.getSample(id);
        if (sample == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return sample;
    }
}
```

Service layer encapsulating business logic

```
@Service
public class SampleService {
    private static final Map<Integer, Sample> samples = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        samples.put(1, new Sample(1, "sample1"));
        samples.put(2, new Sample(2, "sample2"));
    }

    public Sample getSample(int id) {
        return samples.get(id);
    }
}
```

Unit test for the above resource

```
public class SampleResourceTest extends SpringContextAwareJerseyTest {
    private SampleService mockSampleService;

    // create mock object for our test
    @Bean
    static public SampleService sampleService() {
        return Mockito.mock(SampleService.class);
    }

    /**
     * Create our own resource here so only the test resource is loaded. If
     * we use @ComponentScan, the whole package will be scanned and more
     * resources may be loaded (which is usually NOT what we want in a test).
     */
    @Bean
    static public SampleResource sampleResource() {
        return new SampleResource();
    }

    // get the mock objects from the internal servlet context, because
    // the app context may get recreated for each test so we have to set
    // it before each run
    @Before
    public void setupMocks() {
         mockSampleService = getContext().getBean(SampleService.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMock() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(mockSampleService);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetSample() {
        // see how the mock object hijack the sample service, now id 3 is valid
        Sample sample3 = new Sample(3, "sample3");
        Mockito.when(mockSampleService.getSample(3)).thenReturn(sample3);

        expect().statusCode(200).get(SERVLET_PATH + "/sample/3");
        String jsonStr = get(SERVLET_PATH + "/sample/3").asString();
        Assert.assertNotNull(jsonStr);
    }

}
```

SpringContextAwareJerseyTest

```
@Configuration
public class SpringContextAwareJerseyTest extends JerseyTest {
    protected static String SERVLET_PATH = "/api";

    final private static ThreadLocal<ApplicationContext> context =
        new ThreadLocal<>();

    protected String getResourceLocation() {
        return "example.rest";
    }

    protected String getContextConfigLocation() {
        return getClass().getName();
    }

    static private String getContextHolderConfigLocation() {
        return SpringContextAwareJerseyTest.class.getName();
    }

    protected WebAppDescriptor configure() {
        String contextConfigLocation = getContextConfigLocation() + " " +
            getContextHolderConfigLocation();

        Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<>();
        initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages",
                       getResourceLocation());
        initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");

        return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder(initParams)
            .servletClass(SpringServlet.class)
            .contextParam(
                "contextClass",
                "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext")
            .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", contextConfigLocation)
            .servletPath(SERVLET_PATH)  // if not specified, it set to root resource
            .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
            .requestListenerClass(RequestContextListener.class)
            .build();
    }

    protected final ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context.get();
    }

    @Bean
    public static ContextHolder contextHolder() {
        return new ContextHolder();
    }

    private static class ContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {
        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
            context.set(applicationContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the above with jersey 1.8